# VBA Macro triggers different Macro from workbook open

Tags: vba, excel, events, userform

I have a fairly straight forward piece of code in the ThisWorkbook sheet in VBA. As you can see this code populates a combobox with a server name. The idea is that the user will select this server after opening the workbook and the then this will activate a macro based on the server variable to populate a second combobox with a list of databases.

In order to populate this combobox a macro called CB_Server_Change uses an ADODB connection to reach out to the server and pull back the database names for the user to select.

However on opening this workbook the workbook freezes and eventually debugs with a unable to connect to server error. Which is not surprising because on opening the workbook the user hasn't had the chance to select any variables.

On trying to debug this, I have found that on stepping through the .AddItem "M01-SQL-P09-DB2" to move onto the .ListIndex = 0 line it just jumps to the macro on worksheet (Control Menu) where the combobox resides and tries to run the CB_Server_Change macro?

I cannot work out why its not just populating the combobox as requested, I'm not referencing the Control Menu sheet at all or the CB_Server_Change macro in the ThisWorkbook Workbook_Open() macro.

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

        With Worksheets("Control Menu").CB_Server
            .Clear
            .AddItem "Select Server"
            .AddItem "M01-SQL-P09-DB2"
            .ListIndex = 0
        End With

    'Restore the settings.
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

has anyone come across this before? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think you might be triggering the change event when populating.  Try adding public var, called `blnSetup` or something like that.  Set this to true when populating and false after, then check this var in the change event.

Comment: What type of control is this? I've tried with both Form Controls and ActiveX controls and both raise a compile error if I try to reference them like `Worksheets("Sheet1").DropDown1` (form) or `Worksheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1` (activex)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav - when reading the question I was about to formulate this as an answer, but you beat me to it with a comment. You should turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: Instead of .AddItem "Select Server" you can also use .Text "Select Server" as it is not a real menu-item. (this will also trigger the change, but you can leave .ListIndex out)

Comment: Thanks EvR, this didn't work, I just got a Run-time error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Thanks David this is an ActiveX Combobox.

Comment: Oops, I missed an = when Typing/copying :  .Text = "Select Server"

Answer (score 1):

The `ListIndex=0` assignment triggers an `OnChanged` event, just like a user selection of an item would.  I was able to reproduce this in Excel 2013 by:

- Creating an empty XLSM
- Adding an ActiveX ComboBox to Sheet1
- Selecting `Developer | View Code`, which created a `ComboBox1_Change` function in `Sheet1`.
- Adding `Debug.Print "Changed"` to `ComboBox1_Change`
- In `ThisWorkbook`, adding a sub:

  ```
  Private Sub Workbook_Open()
      Debug.Print "Opening"
      With Sheet1.ComboBox1
          .Clear
          .AddItem "foo"
          .AddItem "bar"
          .ListIndex = 0
      End With
      Debug.Print "done opening"
  End Sub
  ```
- Saving, closing, and reopening.  Result (in the Immediate window):

  ```
  Opening
  Changed
  done opening
  ```

So you can try either of two things:

1. Don't set `ListIndex`.  If I comment out that line, the `Change` event doesn't fire (I do not get a "Changed" message in the Immediate window).
2. Use @Nathan_Sav's idea: manually tell the combobox `Change` code not to do anything.

Example of the second idea:

In `ThisWorkbook`, add a variable:

```
Option Explicit

Public Initialized As Boolean     ' <--- new

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Debug.Print "Opening"
    Initialized = False           ' <---
    With Sheet1.ComboBox1
        .Clear
        .AddItem "foo"
        .AddItem "bar"
        .ListIndex = 0
    End With
    Initialized = True            ' <---
    Debug.Print "done opening"
End Sub
```

In `Sheet1`, add:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If ThisWorkbook.Initialized Then  ' <--- test the variable
        Debug.Print "Changed"
    End If
End Sub
```

That way, if you are still initializing (still in `Workbook_Open`), you can skip the code you don't want to run.  When I open a workbook with the above code, I do not get a "Changed" message in the Immediate window, indicating the test of `Initialized` is working as expected.

Comment: Shouldn't setting `Application.EnableEvents` to `False` prevent the Change event from being raised ??

Comment: Besides .ListIndex .Clear will trigger the change Event also. (when there are items to clear)

Answer (score 1):

i think you might be triggering the change event when populating. Try adding public var, called blnSetup or something like that. Set this to true when populating and false after, then check this var in the change event.

```
blnSetup=True
With Worksheets("Control Menu").CB_Server
     .Clear
     .AddItem "Select Server"
     .AddItem "M01-SQL-P09-DB2"
     .ListIndex = 0
End With
blnSetup=false
```

then in the combo change event

```
if not blnSetup then
     ......
end if
```

Comment: You don't really have a need for the public var, you could check the `listindex>0` instead perhaps.